# How can I set a variable = null in for loop?

Tags: for-loop, centos, elastix

I have this code in Elastix2.5 (CentOS):

```
for variable in $(while read line; do myarray[ $index]="$line"; index=$(($index+1)); echo "$line"; done < prueba);
```

This extract the values for each line from "prueba" file.

Prueba file contents passwords like this:

```
Admin1234
Hello543
Chicken5444

Dino6759
3434Cars4

Adminis5555
```

But, `$variable` only get values from lines where there are letters, I need that it get `NULL` values from blank lines. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is use of a `for` loop with a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`$(...)`); let's look at this simple example:

```
$ for v in $(echo 'line_1'; echo ''; echo 'line_3'); do echo "$v"; done
line_1
line_3
```

Note how the empty string produced by the 2nd `echo` command is effectively discarded.
Analogously, any empty lines produced by your `while` loop are discarded.

The solution is to **[avoid `for` loops altogether for parsing command output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)**:

In your case, simply use *only* the `while` loop for iterating over the input file:

```
while read -r line; do 
  myarray[index++]="$line"
done < prueba
printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"
```

- `-r` was added to ensure that `read` doesn't modify the input (doesn't try to interpret `\`-prefixed sequences) - this is good practice in general.
- Note how incrementing the index was moved directly into the array subscript (`index++`).
- `printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"` prints all array elements after the file's been read, demonstrating that empty lines were read as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use is_null function.

```
is_null($a)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: This is for CentOS, not for PHP.